# Python - Check if list of numbers is in list of numbers

Tags: python, list, numbers

I got a a list of numbers:

```
l = [1,2,3]
```

And I want to check if the numbers in that list are inside another list, like this one

```
l2 = [2,5,1,3,4]
```

This one should return `True`

Any ideas? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
print(set(l) <= set(l2))
# True
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set):

> **set <= other**
> Test whether every element in the set is in *other*.

Answer (score 0):

`all()` method would check if list 1 is in list 2. For example:

```
l = [1,2,3]
l2 = [2,5,1,3,4]
status = all(item in l for item in l2)
```

In this case, `status` will be **True** as `1,2,3` are in **l2**. I hope, this answers your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
l = [1,2,3]
l2 = [2,5,1,3,4]
for i in l:
    for j in l2:
        if i == j:
            break
print(True)
```

The result will be **True** in the end.